# Apache Edge Server putting SSL certs in header vs. reattaching them

Tags: apache, ssl, biztalk, biztalk-2010

We have an Apache servers, edge servers, running as a reverse proxy (in this scenario).

When a user connects to these servers they're required to use SSL X509 certs.

At one point a request has to be made to an ESB running BizTalk 2010.

When the Apache servers pass the request onto BizTalk, Apache is putting the SSL in the header of the message rather than "re-attaching" the SSL certificate, or re-sending the SSL certificate when the request goes out to the ESB. BizTalk is unable to, or I'm not sure how to configure it, read these SSL's that come with the request.

Is there a way of configuring Apache to send SSL's with a message that BizTalk can understand, when Apache is running as a reverse proxy? Or is there a way to configure BizTalk to read these SSL certs that come in the header?

Update:

Is Apache decrypting the entire SSL stack, and that's why it's having a hard time passing the SSL through normally? Is there any way to resolve this?

Someone recommended that we put all the client certs on Apache, and have Apache just load up one of those to and pass that on with the request to BizTalk. Any other ways around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use S/MIME components with BizTalk to pull off a certificate from a message. It sounds similar to what Apache is doing. Depending on what pipeline component you used, you would specify the certificate details as a property on the component. It is hard to tell you exactly which component (built-in or 3rd party) to use without more information on the the way Apache is doing this.

Is the SSL approach called SSL offloading? I recommend not putting the certs on the Apache server if you can avoid it because it will be more difficult to manage (from an ESB perspective). You would also lose some security between the Apache server and the BizTalk server.